# Rotating a 3D plot in jupyter notebook (previous solutions have a problem)

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, rotation, jupyter-notebook

```
r = range(0,206,1)
hf = plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
ha = hf.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')



X, Y = np.meshgrid(r, r)  # plot_surface expects x and y data to be 2D
ha.plot_wireframe(X, Y, U4[:,:,2000], color='red', alpha=0.6)
ha.plot_wireframe(X,Y, U4[:,:,1000], color='yellow', alpha=0.6)
ha.plot_wireframe(X,Y, U4[:,:,500], color='green', alpha=0.6)
ha.set_zlim3d(0,10)

# rotate the axes and update
for angle in range(0, 360):
    ha.view_init(30, angle)
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(.001)
```

Is my code. What happens is it plots it for the first angle and then follows with an error from plt.pause() line "TypeError: show() got an unexpected keyword argument 'block'". I have put `%matplotlib notebook` at the top of my code, restarted the kernal and ran again to no avail.

If I run `%matplotlib inline` instead i get the first angle plot followed by loads of lines `<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x7fb2ab20eeb8>` but no errors.